# PDF with SWF to web page

Tags: pdf, flash, html, swfobject

I've included (finally) a youtube video into a PDF using Adobe Acrobat X Pro, but when I'm trying to "publish" it into my web page, I can't play the video. This video is a SWF object.

I also tried to create a HTML code with the video using Adobe InDesign, but it shows a black frame. What can I do to publish it? How can I include it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a web based open source viewer like FlexPaper instead so that you also maximize your browser coverage. It supports embedding youtube videos in your documents out of the box. Have a look at it here:

http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/flexpaper_flip_zine.jsp